# Need help removing strange characters from string

Tags: java, notepad++

Currently when I make a signature using java.security.signature, it passes back a string.
I can't seem to use this string since there are special characters that can only be seen when i copy the string into notepad++, from there if I remove these special characters I can use the remains of the string in my program.

In notepad they look like black boxes with the words ACK GS STX SI SUB ETB BS VT

I don't really understand what they are so its hard to tell how to get ride of them.

Is there a function that i can run to remove these and potentially similar characters?

when i use the base64 class supplied in the posts, i cant go back to a signature

```
System.out.println(signature);
String base64 = Base64.encodeBytes(sig);
System.out.println(base64);
String sig2 = new String (Base64.decode(base64));
System.out.println(sig2);
```

gives the output

```
”zÌý¥y]žd”xKmËY³ÕN´Ìå}ÏBÊNÈ›`Î‘rp~jÖüñ0…Rõ…•éh?ÞÀ_û_¥ÂçªsÂk{6H7œÉ/”âtTK±Ï…Ã/Ùê²
lHrM/aV5XZ5klHhLbctZs9VOtMzlfc9Cyk7Im2DOkXJwfmoG1vzxMIVS9YWV6Wg/HQLewF/7X6XC56pzwmt7DzZIN5zJL5TidFRLsc+Fwy/Z6rIaNA2uVlCh3XYkWcu882tKt2RySSkn1heWhG0IeNNfopAvbmHDlgszaWaXYzY=
[B@15356d5
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The odd characters are there because cryptographic signatures produce bytes rather than strings. Consequently if you want a printable representation you should [Base64 encode it](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64) ([here's a public domain implementation for Java](http://iharder.sourceforge.net/current/java/base64/)).

Stripping the non-printing characters from a cryptographic signature will render it useless as you will be unable to use it for verification.

Update:

> [B@15356d5

This is the result of toString called on a byte array. "[" means array, "B" means byte and "15356d5" is the address of the array. You should be passing the array you get out of decode to [Signature.verify](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/security/Signature.html#verify(byte[])).

Something like:

```
Signature sig = new Signature("dsa");
sig.initVerify(key);
sig.verify(Base64.decode(base64)); // <-- bytes go here
```

Comment: does the base64 conversion of a signature still hold up as a valid signature from the technical stand point?

Comment: It will contain all the data, that's what counts. The base64 encoding will have to be reversed before using it to check the signature's validity.

Comment: I'm having issues changing the base64 conversion to a signature again, I've updated the my intial post

Answer (score 5):

How are you "making" the signature? If you use the `sign` method, you get back a byte array, not a string. That's not a binary representation of some text, it's just arbitrary binary data. That's what you should use, and if you need to convert it into a string you should use a base64 conversion to avoid data corruption.

Comment: do i base64 convert the signatures byte array?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your problem correctly, you need to get rid of characters with code below 32, except maybe char 9 (tab), char 10 (new line) and char 13 (return).

**Edit:** I agree with the others as handling a crypto output like this is not what you usually want.

Comment: "Getting rid of" data in a cryptographic signature is rarely a good idea... I strongly suspect it's a more fundamental problem.