# Strange char after reading from txt file

Tags: java, inputstream, bufferedreader

I have a txt file with three rows of integers, after adding them to a List I'm finding a strange char at the beginning of the first index. I used an InputStream, BufferedReader and StringBuilder to read from the file. I tried to debug using println() statements at several places but I still can't figure out where that char came from.

```
 File selectedFile = fileChooser.getSelectedFile();
                    inputStream = new FileInputStream(selectedFile);
                    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
                    StringBuilder out = new StringBuilder();
                    String line;
                    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                        out.append(line);
                        items.add(line);
                    }
```

When I try to copy the output from printing out List items to this post somehow the char I'm talking about does not show, so I'll post a screenshot instead:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/TKgiU.jpg

http://imgur.com/JHAH6mV

The first is of the entire list, and the second should show the char I'm talking more clearly, it looks like a dot before "3". Any help would be appreciated, Thank you.

Comment: have you tried by creating a new test file and reading from it ? Does it reproduce this issue ?

Comment: Does the text file has a [BOM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark)?

Comment: @Seelenvirtuose I don't think so.

Comment: @coder I feel really dumb now, I've spent hours debugging the entire program but for some reason I didn't think of this. I tried a new test file and the char is gone. Thank you!

Comment: You could try FileReader which uses default charset.  If dosent work try Inputstream constructor with choice of your charset

Answer (score 0):

You can try removing all control characters (strange characters) by doing the following:

```
strangeString.replaceAll("\\p{Cntrl}", "");
```

Reference: [Java - removing strange characters from a String](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5462693/java-removing-strange-characters-from-a-string)

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for the help. The problem was actually in the original txt file like @coder