# How to remove this non-standard unicode character?

Tags: java, unicode

I have a function 'remove4BytesUTF8Char()' to remove some unique characters that appear in social media, but it doesn't do the job. I can remove lots of other characters, but not this one. How to get rid of this specifically from my String?

```
        String str = "very good\uE056 flavor";
        System.out.println("str before remove: " + str);
        str = UTF8Utils.remove4BytesUTF8Char(str);
        System.out.println("str after remove " + str);
```

The output is below:

```
str before remove: very good flavor
str after remove very good flavor
```

Edit:

```
public static String remove4BytesUTF8Char(String s) {
        byte[] bytes = s.getBytes();
        byte[] removedBytes = new byte[bytes.length];
        int index = 0;

        String hex;
        String firstChar;
        for (int i = 0; i < bytes.length; ) {
            hex = UTF8Utils.byteToHex(bytes[i]);

            if (hex.length() < 2) {
                System.out.println("fail to check whether contains 4 bytes char(1 byte hex char too short), default return false.");
                // todo, throw exception for this case
                return null;
            }

            firstChar = hex.substring(0, 1);

            if (byteMap.get(firstChar) == null) {
                System.out.println("fail to check whether contains 4 bytes char(no firstchar mapping), default return false.");
                // todo, throw exception for this case
                return null;
            }

            if (firstChar.equals("f")) {
                for (int j = 0; j < byteMap.get(firstChar); j++) {
                    i++;
                }
                continue;
            }

            for (int j = 0; j < byteMap.get(firstChar); j++) {
                removedBytes[index++] = bytes[i++];
            }
        }

        return new String(Arrays.copyOfRange(removedBytes, 0, index));
    }
```

Comment: Have you already looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5462747/5645656)?

Comment: You havent posted your function remove4BytesUTF8Char. We can’t help without the code that has the problem.

Comment: "Hey mechanic Joe. My car doesn't work, so I left it at home and drove here on my bike. Can you please look at my bike and tell me what is wrong with my car?" *<sigh>*

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt, I added the function I am using.

Comment: **Caution:** `s.getBytes()` will not return UTF-8 bytes on Windows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just treat the `String` as an array of `char`s and then see if each `char` is greater than 127 since that is the [largest value for ascii](http://www.asciitable.com/) so anything higher would be part of utf8

```
public static void main(String...args){
    String str = "very good\uE056 flavor";
    System.out.println(str);
    System.out.println(removeUTF8(str));
}

public static String removeUTF8(String s){
    for(int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++){
        char targetChar = s.charAt(i);
        if(targetChar > 127){
            s = s.replaceAll(Character.toString(targetChar), "");
        }
    }
    return s;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

All char, Character and String use the UTF-16 encoding of Unicode. Each codepoint is encoded in one or two code units (`char`). Two for >= U+10000. [Clause D91](http://www.unicode.org/versions/Unicode10.0.0/ch03.pdf#G7404)

UTF-8 is another encoding for Unicode. Each codepoint is encoded in one, two, three, or four code units, (`byte` when you serialize them). Four for >= U+10000. [Table 3-7](http://www.unicode.org/versions/Unicode10.0.0/ch03.pdf#G7404)

So, if you want to filter out codepoints that UTF-8 encodes with 4 bytes, that is the same as filtering out codepoints that UTF-16 encodes with 2 char.

Now, the 2 chars for any of the codepoints that UTF-16 encodes in 2 chars are always in the range '\uD800' to '\uDFFF'. (They correspond to the [surrogate codepoints](http://unicode.org/faq/utf_bom.html#utf16-2) that are reserved to prevent confusion.)

Okay, so that's what your remove4BytesUTF8Char function is intended to handle. But, '\uE056' actually isn't a UTF-16 code unit for a Unicode codepoint that UTF-8 encodes in 4 bytes. It's in Unicode's [Private Use Area](http://www.unicode.org/charts/nameslist/index.html) block (scroll down in left frame): U+E000 to U+F8FF ('\uE000" to '\uF8FF'). So, you'd have to filter out those separately.

```
String input = "very good\uE056 flavor ";
System.out.println(input);
String output = input.chars() // IntStream of UTF-16 code units
    .filter(c -> !Character.isSurrogate((char)c) 
                 && Character.getType((char)c) != Character.PRIVATE_USE)
    .collect(StringBuilder::new, StringBuilder::appendCodePoint, StringBuilder::append)
    .toString(); 
System.out.println(output);
```